# Nested objects have not been saved by Spring JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, repository, spring-roo, spring-data

I have a Spring Roo application with GWT. On server-side I´ve got simple JpaRepository interfaces for all entities like:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyEntity>, JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
}
```

There is a MyEntity class that has a One-To-One relationship to a MyOtherEntity class.
When I call my entity-service persist method

```
public void saveMyEntity (MyEntity myEntity) {
    myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
}
```

only the myEntity object will be saved. All sub objects of MyEntity are ignored. The only way to save the myEntity object along with the myOtherEntity object is calling

```
    myOtherEntityRepository.save(myOtherEntity);
```

before the above code. So is there a more elegant way to automatically save sub objects with JpaRepository interface?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't know your implementation details. But, I think, it just need to use `CascadeType` in `JPA`. JPA Reference [CascadeType](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/Cascade-Action.htm).

Try as below.

```
public class MyEntity {
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST) <or> @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) <-- for all operation
    @JoinColumn(name = "YOUR-ID")
    private MyOtherEntity myOtherEntity ;
}
```

For Recursiivce MyEntity Relationship

```
public class MyEntity {
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST) <or> @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) <-- for all operation
    @JoinColumn(name = "YOUR-ID")
    private MyEntity myEntity ;
}
```